# count number of tab characters in linux

Tags: bash, unix, csh, grep

I want to count the numbers of `hard tab characters` in my documents in unix shell.

How can I do it?

I tried something like

`grep -c \t foo`

but it gives counts of t in file foo.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of tab chars or the number of lines containing tab chars? In the example you gave, if `\t` had worked, you'll get the latter (*number of lines containing tabs*).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use tr to discard everything except tabs, and then count:

```
< input-file tr -dc \\t | wc -c
```

Comment: Wonder who else is here looking to answer this https://cmdchallenge.com/#/find_tabs_in_a_file :)

Answer (score 11):

Bash uses a `$'...'` notation for specifying special characters:

```
grep -c $'\t' foo
```

Comment: That counts the number of lines with a tab, not the number of tabs.

Answer (score 4):

Use a perl regex (`-P` option) to grep tab characters.

So, to count the number of tab characters in a file:

```
grep -o -P '\t' foo | wc -l
```

Comment: -P is GNU only and this post is not tagged Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a literal TAB character between the quotes with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

In general you can insert any character at all by prefixing it with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>; even control characters such as <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> that the shell would otherwise interpret.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk in a tricky way: use tab as the record separator, then the number of tab characters is the total number of records minus 1:

```
ntabs=$(awk 'BEGIN {RS="\t"} END {print NR-1}' foo)
```

Comment: And to count the number of tab characters per line : `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{print NF-1}' foo` (`FS` being `awk`'s field separator).

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use `sed` to strip out all non-tab characters, then use `wc` to count the number of characters left.

```
< foo.txt sed 's/[^\t]//g' | wc -c
```

However, this also counts newlines, which `sed` won't touch because it is line-based. So, let's use `tr` to translate all the newlines into spaces, so it is one line for `sed`.

```
< foo.txt tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/[^\t]//g' | wc -c
```

Depending on your shell and implementation of `sed`, you may have to use a literal tab instead of `\t`, however, with Bash and GNU `sed`, the above works.